# Example for longtable package use

Tags: longtable

I am trying to use the longtable package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \centering
    \caption{$\chi^2$ - Test of UDP Packet Size Sample Measurements}
    \hline
    \textbf{Bin Interval Lower Bound} & \textbf{Bin Interval Upper Bound} & \textbf{Histogram Count} & \textbf{Expected Count} & \textbf{Cumulative Distribution} & \textbf{$\chi^2$ - Value}
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{6}{c}
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Bin Interval Lower Bound} & \textbf{Bin Interval Upper Bound} & \textbf{Histogram Count} & \textbf{Expected Count} & \textbf{Cumulative Distribution} & \textbf{$\chi^2$ - Value}
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

        1000  & 1003,99 & 102   & 100   & 102   & 0,04 \\
        1004  & 1007,99 & 105   & 100   & 207   & 0,25 \\
        1008  & 1011,99 & 104   & 100   & 311   & 0,16 \\
        1012  & 1015,99 & 104   & 100   & 415   & 0,16 \\

\label{Table1}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working. TeXstudio throws some errors such as "Misplaces \omit. \endhead"

Can anyone see what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: you need `\\ ` after `\caption` and delete `\centering`

Comment: ok, did that. But the error remains. I have deleted `\centering`, but instead I have put `\begin{center}` before `\begin{longtable}` and ofc  `end{center}` after  `\end{longtable}` .. can it be that sth is wrong with `{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}}\\`  , because I don't really understand this line. I have copied from an example

Comment: no \begin{center}` around a longtable is always wrong (but doesn't generate an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, this table can't fit  between margins  of a normal paper size. One has to rotate the column heads. Does this code compile normally for you?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\boldmath\bfseries}
\settowidth{\rotheadsize}{\bfseries Upper Bound}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \caption{$\chi^2$-Test of UDP Packet Size Sample Measurements}
\label{Table1}\\
    \hline
    \rothead{Bin Interval\\ Lower Bound} & \rothead{Bin Interval\\ Upper Bound} & \rothead{Histogram\\ Count} & \rothead{Expected\\ Count} & \rothead{Cumulative\\ Distribution} & \rothead{$\chi^2$-Value} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{6}{c}
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \rothead{Bin Interval\\ Lower Bound} & \rothead{Bin Interval\\ Upper Bound} & \rothead{Histogram\\ Count} & \rothead{Expected\\ Count} & \rothead{Cumulative\\ Distribution} & \rothead{$\chi^2$-Value} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
        1000 & 1003,99 & 102 & 100 & 102 & 0,04 \\
        1004 & 1007,99 & 105 & 100 & 207 & 0,25 \\
        1008 & 1011,99 & 104 & 100 & 311 & 0,16 \\
        1012 & 1015,99 & 104 & 100 & 415 & 0,16 \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it gives me `undefined control sequence. \rothead`

Comment: Do you have all  the required packages installed?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I did not. But now I included everything, and it gives me `option clash for package geometry. \usepackage` for the `\usepackage{rotating}`

Comment: The option clash comes from `geometry` already loaded, without this option. It is only used  to visualise the margins and see  if there's an overflow into the margin. You may safely remove loafding `geometry`. Should you want  the framed option, you can pass it as an option in the document class anyway.

Comment: I just realized the following: My table actually continues along 4 pages. For some reason, the table is spaced a little bit more to the left on both the second and the fourth page! It is spaced more to the right for the first and the third page. Can you think of a reason for this?

Comment: Normally, it shouldn't. Did you compile several times? The layout of the tables is stabilised after several compilations, in general.

Comment: hm.. I have compiled it a couple of times. I don't remember if it showed up before I added: `\chapter{Chapter 1}` and `\section{Section 1}` before the `\begin{longtable} ` , but this shouldn't have an influence

Comment: ok, I just realized: It must have something to do with the template that I am using: For some reason the page number is also changing from bottom right to bottom left with every page.